# Non vibrating push notifications in-app but not outside of the app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to have push notifications which do not vibrate within the app, but if the app is in background mode and I get a push notification my phone still vibrates. How can I do this, thanks

Comment: vibrate is a inherit behavior for push and local notifications in iOS devices. You cannot change it

Comment: So I can't disable in app vibrations?